# Customizing API keys in Gwibber?

Tags: gwibber, facebook, twitter

in Lucid when i post new status to twitter it says 'via ubuntu' instead of 'via gwibber'. i wonder where gwibber store its settings for the API keys so that i can modify it to anything i like.

Comment: I was wondering this too. I'm a Linux noob so I'm not privy to the ins and outs. I went into the Gwibber settings via gconf-editor and found an API value, a changed it to one that would show via Ubuntu with the Ubuntu logo but it didn't work. When I went back in to double check the API, it was gone. ill investigate later but I think the only way would be to tinker around in the source.

Answer (score 1):

The OAuth consumer key/secret appear to be coming from the `/usr/share/gwibber/data/twitter` file.

These values override the keys from `microblog/util/const.py`, which would presumably be the upstream consumer key.

Comment: Doesn't work - I just tried to do that. It spits out a "Incorrect Signature Error" - http://lts.cr/Vkf

Comment: You need to reauthorize your account after swapping the keys. (deleting the account and readding it does the trick)